# Cyclic Marathon (JBOI 2013)

Tags: algorithm

I found this problem called Cyclic Marathon : http://www.math.bas.bg/infos/files/2013-11-24-B2_eng.pdf from the 2013's JBOI.

I've been trying to solve it for a while, but with no luck... Would you mind guiding me to find a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Visualizing the problem, and I was thinking whether something like comparing the distance of all pairs of runners would help....

Comment: Edit your question and add everything you have tried so far to have a higher chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to store the current runners in a doubly-linked list (to make it easy to remove runners once they have been eliminated).

For each pair of consecutive runners where the first runner is faster than the second, compute the time when they will meet and store this time in a heap data structure (the heap contains the meeting time and a pointer to the second runner).

The heap will allow you to find the next runners to meet (this will be the pair at the top of the heap), and you can then update your data structures in time O(logn) and repeat until the heap is empty.

The update will require:

1. Marking that the second runner is no longer in the race
2. Removing the second runner from the linked list
3. Adding a new meeting time from the first runner to the next in the list (only if the first runner is fast enough)
4. Rebalancing the heap

If the first runner in this meeting has already been removed from the race then the update should be skipped.

Overall this should take time O(nlogn).

Comment: Yeah that's kinda close to what I was thinking...I just realised that a runner can't eliminate another when they are not consecutive, he has to meet more runners in the process. So, we just need to find the time in which two CONSECUTIVE runners will meet.

Comment: And... I can assume that it's just as possible to use a priority queue instead of a heap right?

Comment: @user2455103 A heap is a type of priority queue, and of course you are free to use a different type of priority queue if you prefer.